# Combined use of [fleqn] and \qedhere

Tags: amsmath, amsthm

It seems there is an issue within the ams packages, which results in an incompatibility between the fleqn option, and the \qedhere command.

If those are used together, the qed symbol is flushed to the left of the equation, instead of the right.

In the ams revision history, I see a line about a bugfix with "fleqn/qedhere" issues, which is about amscls version 2.02, while I'm using amsclass (and thus amsthm) version 2.20. I have no idea if the bug they fixed is the same I'm experiencing, though.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
This is a statement.
\begin{proof}
  This is the equation settling it all:
  \begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 3 \qedhere
  \end{equation}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Enclosing the `\qedhere` in a `\mbox{}`, as suggested in amsthm's manual, doesn't produce the wanted output either (the qed is one quad right of the equation).

I'm sure there exists plenty of complicated solutions to this problem, however I'd like to avoid them if possible. More precisely, if I could fix it without changing anything out of my preamble, it would be great.

I have hope, because it seems google can't give me anything relevant to that problem, but I don't believe I'm the only one with it. So I might be missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's surely a bug; but I'd avoid ending a proof with a *numbered* display. Unfortunately, the placement is wrong also with `equation*`. :(

Comment: I'm actually using the mathtools package to number only the equations I need. Even if I will never need this one, it spares the hassle of deciding each time whether the equation should or shouldn't be numbered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution is to use the [ntheorem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\Box$}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}
This is a statement.  Make it long enough that the right margin is clearly delimited.
\begin{proof}
  Use an explicit tag to get the qed box:
  \begin{equation*}
    1 + 1 = 3
  \end{equation*}
  \let\qed\relax
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Comment: Nice! The `\let\qed\relax` line doesn't appear to be necessary. It also works for numbered equations (in which case the qed appears under the equation number), which is undoubtedly ugly. However, surprisingly, with `mathtool`'s `showonlyrefs`, it works for `equation*` but not for `equation` (the `qed` doesn't appear at all).

Answer (score 7):

this definitely is a (known) bug in `amsmath`.  and it's worse than you may realize -- when the qed box is set with `\qedhere`, `fleqn` and an equation number, the equation number protrudes into the right-hand margin.

here's a workaround if you are using `fleqn` and want an end-of-proof box on an equation without an equation number that ends a proof:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\Box$}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
This is a statement.  Make it long enough that the right margin is clearly delimited.
\begin{proof}
  Use an explicit tag to get the qed box:
  \begin{equation*}
    1 + 1 = 3 \tag*{\qedsymbol}
  \end{equation*}
  \let\qed\relax
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

do observe the distinction between `\qedsymbol` and `\qed`; if only the `\qedsymbol` is made to disappear, an extra blank line will be inserted after the display to hold the now-invisible box.

there are several other known problems with `fleqn`, and all are on the list to be looked at and corrected the next time the code is opened up for an overhaul.

Comment: Thank you for that answer! It does indeed work, but I'd rather avoid the use of this `\let...` line at each equation. An alternative would be to use a custom proof environment, but that wouldn't seem natural either.